# How to remove stylesheets only for anonymous users?

Tags: theming, toolbar

I am trying to remove all unnecessary/unused stylesheets for anonymous visitors to get better performance and a clean `<head>` section. This works fine by listing them inside `mytheme.info.yml`:

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - path/to/stylesheet.css
  - path/to/another/stylesheet.css
  - core/modules/system/css/components/hidden.module.css
```

However, the third entry in this example breaks the styling of the toolbar - which is only visible to the admin. Is it possible to programatically tell Drupal which stylesheets to remove only for anonymous visitors? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried to do this myself before, this is probably not a route you want to go down.  This approach becomes harder to maintain as you install more modules (different modules can inject CSS on different paths), and often can turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Drupal can aggregate CSS files out of the box; this is often all you need to improve performance dramatically.

To turn on the basic aggregation, you can check **Aggregate CSS files** at `/admin/config/development/performance`.

To do something more complicated, try using the [Advagg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module. Configuring this module can be complex but it allows you to do more specific aggregation, CSS minification, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this solution is definitely better for maintainability. I will take a look at the Advagg module as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

you can use hook bellow (check for the right path)

```
function MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  if(\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    unset($attachments['#attached']['library']['core/modules/system/css/components/hidden.module.cs']);
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the way to go, although I think it has to be `$attachments['#attached']['library'][0]` in order to remove all the system css stuff. Thanks!

Comment: You can only remove libraries but not a single CSS file like that.

Comment: You can only remove libraries added by other hook_page_attachments or hook_page_attachments_alter implementations.

Comment: @4k4 – ... or added from a theme's info file.

Comment: @leymannx, no, these hooks are invoked starting with an empty array, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21MainContent%21HtmlRenderer.php/function/HtmlRenderer%3A%3AinvokePageAttachmentHooks/9.0.x

Comment: @4k4 – Well, somehow Bartik's `bartik/global-styling` landed there and I could easily unset it using this hook. And this library hasn't been added from a hook before.

Comment: `$attachments['#attached'['library'['core/modules/system/css/components/hidden.module.cs']` contains a syntax error.

Comment: @leymannx - Theme libraries are added by [system_page_attachments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_page_attachments/9.0.x), so you are right with your comment about the theme's info file.

Comment: @4k4 – Ah yeah, I couldn't find that place. A hook, of course. So you were right as well. ^^